# Autoreferencing bug with subfigure created with \subbottom command

Tags: subfloats, autoref

I have a figure with subfigures, and try to \autoreference them as per usual.
However, I noticed a strange bug: The first one (subfigure a)) gets referenced as Fig.() instead of Figure 4.1(a). The one after that gets referenced as Figure 4.1(a) instead of Figure 4.1(b).
Do any of you know the reason/solution and can help me out?

```
This becomes evident in \autoref{fig:tivTmodeshape1} for mode 1 and \autoref{fig:tivTmodeshape2} for mode 2.
```

> This becomes evident inFigure 4.2()for mode 1 and4.2(a)for mode 2.

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
    ~
    \subbottom[Mode Shape 1]{
        \includegraphics[trim=3cm 0 3cm 0,clip,width=.45\textwidth]{fig/tstruct/TstructFDD-modeShape1.eps}
        \label{fig:tivTmodeshape1}
    }
    ~
    \subbottom[Mode Shape 2]{
        \includegraphics[trim=3cm 0 3cm 0,clip,width=.45\textwidth]{fig/tstruct/TstructFDD-modeShape2.eps}
        \label{fig:tivTmodeshape2}
    }
    ~
    \subbottom[Mode Shape 3]{
        \includegraphics[trim=3cm 0 3cm 0,clip,width=.28\textwidth]{fig/tstruct/TstructFDD-modeShape3.eps}
        \label{fig:tivTmodeshape3}
    }
    ~
    \subbottom[Mode Shape 4]{
        \includegraphics[trim=3cm 0 3cm 0,clip,width=.28\textwidth]{fig/tstruct/TstructFDD-modeShape4.eps}
        \label{fig:tivTmodeshape4}
    }
    ~
    \subbottom[Mode Shape 5]{
        \includegraphics[trim=3cm 0 3cm 0,clip,width=.28\textwidth]{fig/tstruct/TstructFDD-modeShape5.eps}
        \label{fig:tivTmodeshape5}
    }
    \caption{The first 5 mode shapes of the structure with sensor locations depicted}
\label{fig:tivTmodeshapesAll5}
\end{figure}
```

I kinda suspect that this might be due to the \subbottom command, which I haven't used before, but I'm not sure.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: The document class is memoir, and I think the relevant package is graphicx:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class (`memoir`, right?) you employ and which packages you load in order to make the code fragment above compilable.

Comment: Hi, yes, it's memoir. See the above main post edited with what I think are the relevant packages.

Comment: Make a *complete* and *compilable* example. Replace the graphics by \includegraphics{example-image}.

Comment: Note that the label should be in the [] part, not the {}, if you haven't used subbottom before, I'd probably recommend using subcaption or similar (I think that's the name). Memoirs subbottom is probably not compatible with autoref

Comment: Thank you very much daleif, that fixed it!
By the way, autoref still works. :)